# Derive the exponential distribution function

Tags: probability

I know that the density function of a standard exponential distribution is:

$$f(x)= e^{-x}  , \quad x>0$$

How can I prove that the distribution function is:

$$F(x)=1-e^{-x}, \quad x>0$$

Attempt to solve this:

I know that I need to take the integral of the density function:

$$F(x)= -e^{-x}+C$$

From here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Remember that exponential distribution is valid for $x \ge 0$ only. So $F(X=0)=0$ . Substituting this you get c=1

Comment: This is incorrect. C is part of the indefinite integral, which is cancelled out when you do subtraction of F(x) - F(0).

Comment: The "1" comes from the fact that we are doing a subtraction of the anti-derivative and F(0) = (-1 * exp(0)) = (-1). Therefore F(X) - F(0) = (- exp(-x)) - (- 1) = 1 - exp(-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that (for a continuous random variable), the CDF $F_X(x)$ is the integral of the PDF from $-\infty$ to $x$. What you've found is the indefinite integral--you just need to evaluate it at the appropriate limits of integration (remember that the exponential PDF $f_X(x)$ is zero for $x<0$).

Answer (score 4):

$F(x)=\int_0^xe^{-u}du=1-e^{-x}$.